# Kubernetes StatefulSets: External DNS

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubernetes [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset) create internal DNS entries with stable network IDs. The docs describe this here:

> Each Pod in a StatefulSet derives its hostname from the name of the
>   StatefulSet and the ordinal of the Pod. The pattern for the
>   constructed hostname is $(statefulset name)-$(ordinal). The example
>   above will create three Pods named web-0,web-1,web-2. A StatefulSet
>   can use a Headless Service to control the domain of its Pods. The
>   domain managed by this Service takes the form: $(service
>   name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local, where “cluster.local” is the
>   cluster domain. As each Pod is created, it gets a matching DNS
>   subdomain, taking the form: $(podname).$(governing service domain),
>   where the governing service is defined by the serviceName field on the
>   StatefulSet.

I am experimenting with headless services, and this works great for communication between individual services i.e `web-0.web.default.svc.cluster.local` can connect and communicate with `web-1.web.default.svc.cluster.local` just fine.

**Is there any way that I can configure this to work outside of the cluster network as well, where "cluster.local" is replaced with something like "clustera.com"?**

I would like to give another kubernetes cluster, lets call it clusterb.com, access to the individual services of the original cluster (clustera.com); I'm hoping it would look something like clusterb simply hitting endpoints like `web-1.web.default.svc.clustera.com` and `web-0.web.default.svc.clustera.com`.

Is this possible? I would like access to the individual services, not a load balanced endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to test the following solutions and check if they can help you to achieve your goal in your particular scenario:

- The first one is for sure the easiest and I believe that you didn't implemented it for some reason and you did not reported in the question why.

  I am talking about [Headless services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) Without selectors CNAME records for ExternalName-type services.

  > [ExternalName](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-tips-part-1/): Maps the service to the contents of the externalName field (e.g. foo.bar.example.com), by returning a CNAME record with its value. No proxying of any kind is set up. This requires version 1.7 or higher of kube-dns

  Therefore if you need to point a service of an other cluster you will need to register a domain name pointing to the relative IP of `clusterb`.
- The second solution that I have never tested, but I believe it can apply to your case is to make use of a [Federated Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/) whose reason why to use it is accordinding to the documentation:

  > Cross cluster discovery: Federation provides the ability to auto-configure DNS servers and load balancers with backends from all clusters. For example, you can ensure that a global VIP or DNS record can be used to access backends from multiple clusters.